# How can I set age with DatePicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to display age on the text field when I change the date picker. When I choose a date the value doesn't show up on the age text field. How can I display the age when I pick a date? Is there a better way of doing this?

```html
<div class="form-group input-group">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text"> <i class="fa fa-id-card-o"></i> </span>
  </div>
  <input name="age" class="form-control" placeholder="Age" type="text" id="age">
</div>
<div class="form-group input-group">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text"> <i class="fa fa-birthday-cake"></i> </span>
  </div>
  <input name="birthDate" class="form-control" type="date" id="birthDate">
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('change', '.birthDate', function() {
    var a = moment($(this).val(), "MM/DD/YYYY").month(0).from(moment().month(0));
    $('#age').val(a);
  });
})
```

Comment: Please don't use the `php` tag if no PHP is involved.

Comment: The same also goes for multiple versions of Laravel - especially when neither is relevant to the issue. I've edited to remove the redundant tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of issues. Firstly, the element has no `birthDate` class, it's an id. As such the selector needs to be `#birthDate`, not `.birthDate`.

Secondly, the format of the date will depend on the user's locale. For example, mine displays in `YYYY-MM-DD` format. As such your explicit instruction to momentJS to parse the date in `DD/MM/YYYY` format caused it to be read incorrectly. You're better off not specifying the format and letting momentJS determine for itself.

With those issues addressed, try this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $(document).on('change', '#birthDate', function() {
    var a = moment($(this).val()).month(0).from(moment().month(0));
    $('#age').val(a);
  });
})
```

```html
<div class="form-group input-group">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text"> <i class="fa fa-id-card-o"></i> </span>
  </div>
  <input name="age" class="form-control" placeholder="Age" type="text" id="age">
</div>
<div class="form-group input-group">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text"> <i class="fa fa-birthday-cake"></i> </span>
  </div>
  <input name="birthDate" class="form-control" type="date" id="birthDate">
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-qTXRIMyZIFb8iQcfjXWCO8+M5Tbc38Qi5WzdPOYZHIlZpzBHG3L3by84BBBOiRGiEb7KKtAOAs5qYdUiZiQNNQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help